# HTTP сервер с php

Tags: ssl, php, веб-сервер

Доброе время суток. В интернете нашёл пример: [HTTP сервер за 15 минут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/69136/)
В данном веб-сервере нет ни php, ни ssl. По большей части интересует php, можно ли припилить интерпретатор? Есть ли готовые примеры?

Comment: Зачем веб-серверу на ява нужен пшп?  
Обрабатывайте запросы от пользователей средствами самого языка ява.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP-интерпретаторы на Java существуют, например: [faun](http://code.google.com/p/faun/), [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/), так что "припилить" при желании можно всё. Какой ценой, а главное - на кой ляд это нужно - другой вопрос :)

Comment: @klopp, нужно чтоб на этом веб сервере работали php страницы

Comment: Для начала нужно чтобы "это" стало веб-сервером, а не однострочным примером, до этого ещё очень далеко. Но если так хочется извращений и не хочется работать с нормальным сервером, то можно сделать как-нибудь так:

    public void run() 
    {  
       try 
       {
          Request = readInputHeaders();
          writeResponse( ecexPhpCLI(Request) );
        } 

Где метод readInputHeaders() разбирает запрос и готовит данные, а ecexPhpCLI() запускает существующий интерпретатор PHP. Только всё равно эта нелепость сервером не будет :)

Comment: ясно, спасибо =)

Answer (score 2):

В php 5.4 есть встроенный веб сервер.

```
php -S localhost:8000
```